# Gentzen-style proof system with global states?

Tags: proof-theory

I'm sorry if my question looks stupid or does not make sense.
However, I want to ask if it is normal/common to have a global state,
which is shared by all inference rules, in a Gentzen-style proof system?

In particular, the inference rule may maintain a local state `L` and a global state `G`. Any update to the local state `L` of a rule is local only in the scope of this rule and the sub proof tree derived from this rule. Any update to the global state `G` in a rule can be accessed by other rules as well.

For example, `G` and `L` are illustrated in the following `Cut` rule,
where an update that adding `C` to `L ∪ {A}` is local and perceptible.

```
G, L ∪ {A} ⊢ C    G, L ∪ {A,C} ⊢ B
---------------------------------- Cut
          G, L ∪ {A} ⊢ B
```

Let say if this rule is used inside a proof tree, and I also want to update `C` to `G`, so that the new `G` can be used in other part of a proof tree, is this possible to do it?

In particular, in the following proof tree, I want to update `C` into `G` of the `Cut` rule, to have an updated `G*` and this `G*` can be used later to in the application of `Rule2`. Does this make sense when doing this?

```
G*, L ∪ {A} ⊢ C    G*, L ∪ {A,C} ⊢ B          G*, L ∪ {A} ⊢ E
------------------------------------ Cut     ----------------- Rule2
          G, L ∪ {A} ⊢ B                      G, L ∪ {A} ⊢ E
----------------------------------------------------------------- Rule1
                        ..... something here ........
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, then what you refer to as global state is usually just called an axiom system. Such an axiom system is simply a set of formulas, which are assumed to hold without any further proof needed. Now if we have a sequent
$$
\Gamma_0 , \Gamma \to \Delta
$$
where $\Gamma_0$ is a sequence of formulas from an axiom system $G$, then we say that
$$
\Gamma \to \Delta
$$
is provable from $G$ in $\mathbf{LK}$. An interesting fact, by the way, is that
$\Gamma_0 , \Gamma \to \Delta$
is provable in $\mathbf{LK}$ if and only if
$\Gamma \to \Delta$
is provable in $\mathbf{LK}_G$, which is the $\mathbf{LK}$ extended with axiom
$\to g$
for each formula $g \in G$.

If you want to know more about this, then check out section 4 in part 1 of the book about proof theory by Takeuti: [http://www.amazon.com/Proof-Theory-Dover-Books-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00FAUEB32/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1460709504&sr=8-1&keywords=takeuti+proof+theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FAUEB32)

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with your last paragraph, but note that an axiom system cannot be altered within a proof.

Hope this helps anyway!

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation. I will check out the book! :-)